# jQuery 1.7.1 on() not working while live() works

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code snippet

```
$('.box_tile_image').live('click', function() {
console.log('click');   
});
```

The problem is I want to use `on()` as `live()` is deprecated, however if I use **on** in the case above - I do not get "*click*", while if I replace **on** with **live** it works like a breeze.

What can be the problem?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks. Royi Namir answer was more specific for using MyWrapperElement instead of document and he was first. I still upvote your answer and wuold like to accept two answers. Thank you!

Comment: @ lukas: Never be worried about which answer you choose, it's totally up to you. There are some here on SO who will try to bully you; don't let them, it's not their place. I'm just glad my answer helped. Best,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the main selector should be on a *WRAPPER ELEMENT*

```
$('#MyWrapperElement').on('click',".box_tile_image",function() {
console.log('click');   
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent would be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.box_tile_image', function() {
    console.log('click');   
});
```

...and in fact, if you look at the jQuery source from 1.7 onward, that's all `live` is.

Now, that said, I'd strongly recommend hooking the click on something closer to the target elements, rather than all the way up at the `document`. But for a literal equivalent, if the elements in question really have no other common ancestor, that's what you would do.

Comment: This seems natural. Thanks. However why then jQueyr on() documentation has this example: $("#dataTable tbody tr").on("click", function(event){alert($(this).text());});

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: That's hooking the event *directly* on the matching `tr` elements, not using event delegation. `on` is only using event delegation when you supply a selector after the event.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: No worries, glad that helped. Just FWIW, the delegating version of that would be `$('#dataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', ...)` (hooking the `click` on the `tbody`) or `$('#dataTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', ...)` (hooking the `click` on the `#dataTable`).

Comment: thanks! People like you really help a lot and make the SO perfect place for a help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.box_tile_image', function() {
    console.log('click');   
});
```

or you can use [***delegate()***](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).delegate('.box_tile_image', 'click', function() {
    console.log('click');   
});
```

Instead of `document` you can also use any ancestor of `box_title_image`.

Suppose if you have DOM like follwing:

```
<div id="container">
  <img class="box_tile_image" src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Then you can write:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.box_tile_image', function() {
    console.log('click');   
});
```

or

```
$('#container').delegate('.box_tile_image', 'click', function() {
    console.log('click');   
});
```